# Rails 3.2 association methods crashes server & console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to upgrade a Rails 2.3.5 application to Rails 3.2.1.  I know I should have done 3.0 and 3.1 first.  However...

I'm experiencing a very strange problem when I try to access an associated model through an auto generated accessor method.  For instance, I have User and Member models where User has one member and Member belongs to User.  Calling User.first.member will crash the webrick server with no error message.  The same happens in the console with the following output.

```
irb(main):003:0> User.first.member
←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1←[0m

C:\git\web_benebridge\website>rails c
```

Both objects do exist in the database and are linked correctly and this works fine in Rails 2.3.5.

The User model is defined thus:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    require 'digest/sha2'

    belongs_to  :association
    has_one  :member
...
```

And the Member model like this:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :association
...
```

The Association model shown above starts its definition like:

```
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :association_benefits
    has_many :association_kases
    has_many :benefits
    has_many :contacts
    has_many :content_items
    has_many :members
    has_many :users
...
```

I've tried various other models that have associations and some of the association accessor methods work but others do not.  It's really bothersome that there is no error thrown at all, the environment just exits.

One concern I have is that having a model named Association may be confusing things.  Has anyone else run into a problem with this in the later versions of Rails?

Any help resolving this will be greatly appreciated.